# How can I see SQL parameters values in logs on production?

Tags: logging, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In debug mode I can see parameters values in application log, but on production there are '?' parameters values instead. For example:

---

```
2020-08-31T15:42:42.7040466+03:00 [INF] (//) Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@__type_0='?' (Size = 450), @__language_1='?' (Size = 4000)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']" 
""SELECT TOP(1) [n].[type], [n].[create_account_id], [n].[create_date], [n].[Discriminator], [n].[communication_language], [n].[template], [n].[title], [n].[update_account_id], [n].[update_date] FROM [notification_templates] AS [n] WHERE ([n].[Discriminator] = N'SmsTemplates') AND (([n].[type] = @__type_0) AND ([n].[communication_language] = @__language_1))"
```

---

Is there a way to configure it to log actual values?

Comment: which log is this? application log? database server log? how are you logging this information? which logging tool you are using? can you share the logging code and the logging tool configuration?

Comment: It is very strange to ask a c# question without any c# code line.

Comment: Renewed information

Comment: This is likely not Serilog's doing - it has no such cleansing subsystem built-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EnableSensitiveDataLogging** option enables application data to be included in exception messages, logging, etc. This can include the values assigned to properties of your entity instances, parameter values for commands being sent to the database, and other such data. You should only enable this flag if you have the appropriate security measures in place based on the sensitivity of this data. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.enablesensitivedatalogging?view=efcore-5.0)

```
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            ...
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            ...
        }
```